# Array-Based lists and regular arrays

Tags: data-structures, arraylist, hashtable

Are the Array-Based lists and regular arrays the same? And what's the different between hash table and array-based lists when used as a dictionary data structure, is there any trade off between them?

Comment: WTF is array-based list?

Comment: @Soonts http://computerscience.jbpub.com/vbNet/pdfs/McMillan12.pdf

Comment: .NET 1.0? Seriously? The whole platform is deprecated, a decade ago..

Comment: @Soonts I have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Looks like the book you've linked is about version 1.0 or 1.1 of the .NET framework: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET#History The current version is 4.5. No sane person today is developing for .NET version < 3.0. And the collection classes (that your question is about) have changed a lot since 1.0..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A brief on data structures.. with a Java background.

Array, list, and array-list based data structures allow you to access the elements by the order in which they were inserted.

Elements: `3,4,2,1,5`

List: `[3]<->[4]<->[2]<->[1]<->[5]`

Hash map/table based data structures allow you to access the elements by a unique key you associate with it.

Elements: `3,4,2,1,5`

keys: `c,d,b,a,e`

Map:

`[c]->[3]`

`[d]->[4]`

`[b]->[2]`

`[a]->[1]`

`[e]->[5]`

The array (or vector). It offers great speed `O(1)` accessing any element from the array with very low space overhead and you can also iterate backward and forwards from the current element. But the main problem is the array is fixed size, you have to know how many elements you will need when you create the data structure.

The list (double linked list). It offers a dynamically sized data structure (you don't have to know the number of elements at creation) with access to the previous and the new element at a fast speed. But accessing *any* element is very slow `O(n)` and it has a slightly higher space overhead then the array.

The array-list (array based list). Like an array, it offers great speed `O(1)` access to any element and has very low space overhead. Like a list, you don't need to know how many elements will be in the data structure when you create it. But behind the scenes (the user doesn't realize) it is essentially an array which detects when the array will be "full" then it creates a new array (roughly twice the original size) and copies the elements from the old array to the new array.

Hash table is very different from the three data structures above. It doesn't allow access to the elements in the order by which they were inserted. Instead, it allows you to map a key to a value; so you have very fast access `O(1)` to the elements using a unique key.